# Find text in pdf file

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, sdk, cgcontext

How can I extract text from a PDF file using the iPhone SDK and Objective C?

I have successfully read the PDF file, so does anyone have an idea how I can implement this functionality?

Comment: check out below link http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42%22 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103281/pdf-file-text-reading-and-searching