# pdf file text reading and searching

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, pdf, ios4

I want to read text from pdf file and search text into pdf file.

here the link that I know.

none of this help me out.

[Getting text position while parsing pdf with Quartz 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627745/getting-text-position-while-parsing-pdf-with-quartz-2d)

[HIghlighting the text in PDF document iPhone xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755584/highlighting-the-text-in-pdf-document-iphone-xcode)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-CJBDCGCB

[Reading PDF files as string through iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362393/reading-pdf-files-as-string-through-iphone-application)

Comment: Did you look for pdf text extraction?

Comment: if there are not an API already, why not to create one yourself?

Comment: yes i want ti extract text and also search inside pdf.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949809/pdf-viewer-ipad-app) question.

Comment: i dont want to use https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit

Comment: @Fasttracks FastPdf kit is really good,i used this in my application.Well there is no proper documentation for the search in pdf,the available are also not up to date.

Comment: the fast kit pdf shows its logo at the first what about that? and i want to learn how to highlight this..

Comment: There's the FastPdfKit+ version available. The documentation is included in the GitHub project. You can also point your browser at http://doc.mobfarm.eu/FastPdfKit/ also the sample project is heavily commented.

Comment: I am able to parse  pdf page, now i want to highlight particular word in pdf, how can i do so?

Comment: @Fastttracks you need to use CoreText framework to highlight text. and more over you can also hide the logo in fastpdfkit by giving your ownlogo there,you just need to do some tric bro........if you don't want to do that then you can buy this.Well my company only gave me 7 days to do this type off app,so it was not possible for me to do r n d and use core text at my own.So i used that pdf kit.

Comment: can you please provide some information on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-after-rendering

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354457/text-selection-on-pdf-after-rendering-in-iphone

Comment: http://doc.mobfarm.eu/FastPdfKit/ 

its showing a function name of one file which is used to highlight code.

Comment: can we read context of any view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/), it's a good start - it does all the glyph width analysis for you, but it's not perfect either.