# Generate table in PDF

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to create a table in a PDF, in which the data are coming from my iPhone app. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same with **Quartz 2D**, I found an excellent tutorial for this :

[How To Create a PDF with Quartz 2D in iOS 5 Tutorial Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

Check out below link there are many other links to do so, it is called table of contexts.

[pdf file text reading and searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103281/pdf-file-text-reading-and-searching)

Comment: Links are great. but none of the link is able to answer my problem :(