# how to convert pdf to text file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one pdf reader applciation for iPhone in which I want to add one functionality which will conver pdf to text file.

Is it possible?
If possible then please give me idea about that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read this post(s)
[pdf file text reading and searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103281/pdf-file-text-reading-and-searching)

it should get you on the right track