# How to get all content of pdf into string

Tags: objective-c, string, pdf, xcode5

i am facing some problem to get data from PDF to convert into string. i am use following link https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone to get string but unable to pass URL.so any option for it or any other way to refer for getting string from pdf

Comment: where is your file located? means your file in document directory or some where else?

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda my file is located in document directory.

Comment: I added the code in answer for getting pdf data from document directory and convert it into string. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using looks quite old and not updated

Check following links that might help you

https://github.com/vfr/Reader

[Is there any framework to highlight  text on pdf file after rendering on the iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335799/is-there-any-framework-to-highlight-text-on-pdf-file-after-rendering-on-the-iph)

[pdf file text reading and searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103281/pdf-file-text-reading-and-searching)

Comment: i have check that code at the end they are using https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone link code which is i am try but unable to implement. so do you have any other way to do this thing.???